# Keeping state when changing between tabs

Tags: angular, angular5, ng-bootstrap

I am making a reservation application with angular and the reservation goes in a three way process.

In step 1: The `dateFrom` and `dateTo` can be picked which are both `Date` type

In step 2: The amount of reserved items and their price can be selected which is in a class I mad `Formula` with `price: number` and `amount: number`.

In step 3: the checkout will happen this is a form with some input fields

these are in a `reservation-component`. If I want the state off 1,2,3 to stay when swapping between them what is the best approach do I save it all in the `reservation-component` or how can I store it differently? I am thinking of making a `Reservation` class which holds the dateFrom, dateTo and the Formula, but will it really work?
[image: state]

Comment: Asking for a *best approach* is asking for an opinion. That is considered off topic on SO.

Comment: Rxjs Observable will solve your problem.

Comment: I made it and the things is when I switch tabs the state of each class is reset so I'm looking for a way to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store `dateFrom`, `dateTo`, `price` and `amount` as properties of your component. When a user interacts with the form they will simply set the relevant properties, so you are always able to retrieve them with `this.dateFrom`, `this.dateTo`, etc.

Comment: yes but when I switch tabs the state of another tab will be lost.

Comment: I send my date from my datepicker tab to the reservation component like this
`@Output() notifyDateFrom: EventEmitter<Date> = new EventEmitter<Date>();` and I made an overview next to it and I show my data there.

Comment: It'd be helpful to have a look at your current code, can you provide a stackblitz example?